# How do I place new sites onto the newtab page in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I’m using Firefox 33.1 on an iMac running Mac OS X 10.9.5. How do I add new tab icons in the newtab showing the most viewed sites?

Answer (score 1):

In latest firefox instances by default only 9 thumbnails with be shown in new tab page based on frequently visited or latest page visit history. If you wanted to increase the number of rows and columns in tiles use "[new tab tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/?src=cb-dl-updated)" firefox addon.

Note : Add option is replaced with pin option where you can pin certain websites in tiles based on your requirement.